# Lighting in Android, OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, lighting

This is my first question here
The thing is I'm programming an app with OpenGL ES in Android Studio, and I've encountered some problems.
The lights seem to work on the emulator, but when building the APK and installing it on an actual device (with Android 5.0, with opengl es version 3.0 and support for glsl es 3.00), it looks weird:

Emulator, Android Studio 
[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oatuh.png)

Phone:
[Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmaPF.jpg)

It looks like the lighting is not done er fragment on the phone or something, I dont know whats happening. 
Here are the shaders:

```
#version 300 es
uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 P;
uniform int boolGUI;
uniform float opacity;
uniform float blackness;
in vec3 vPosition;
in vec2 vUV;
in vec3 vNormal;
//"in vec3 vColor;" +
//Lights
uniform mat4 lMat;
out mat4 frLMat;

out vec3 frColor;
out vec3 frNormalCam;
//out vec3 frLightCam;
out vec3 frEyeCam;
out vec2 oUV;
out float z;
flat out int frBoolGUI;
flat out float frOpacity;
flat out float frBlackness;
out vec3 frPos;
out mat4 frV;

void main() {
mat4 uMVPMatrix = P * V * M;
vec4 vPos;
vPos.xyz = vPosition;
vPos.w = 1.0;
gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPos;
frColor = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
//vec3 light = vec3(0.3,-0.3,-0.4);
vec3 light = normalize(vec3(-0.1,-0.3,0.2))*0.6;
light = normalize(-vPos.xyz+vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0));
//frLightCam = (V * vec4(light,0)).xyz;
//frNormal = vNormal;
frNormalCam = ( V * M * vec4(normalize(vNormal),0)).xyz;
frEyeCam = (V*vec4(0,-3,2.5,0)).xyz;

oUV = vUV.xy;
z = vPos.z;
frBoolGUI = boolGUI;
frOpacity = opacity;
frBlackness = blackness;
frPos = (M*vPos).xyz;
frV = V;

frLMat=lMat;
}
```

And the fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
in vec3 frColor;
in vec3 frNormalCam;
//in vec3 frLightCam;
in vec3 frEyeCam;
in vec3 frPos;
in vec2 oUV;
in float z;
flat in int frBoolGUI;
flat in float frOpacity;
flat in float frBlackness;
//vec3 l = vec3(1.0,0.1,-0.2);
out vec4 FragColor;
in mat4 frV;
in mat4 frLMat;

uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler;


void main() {

float att = 0.0;
//for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
int i=0;
if(frLMat[i][3]>0.0) {
    vec3 li=frLMat[i].xyz;
    vec3 lightVec = -frPos.xyz+li;//vec3(0.0,-0.5,1.5);
    vec3 light = normalize(lightVec)*0.6;
    vec3 frLightCam = (frV * vec4(light,0)).xyz;


   float lightAtt = 0.6/(length(lightVec))+0.4;
    float ambient = 0.40;

   vec3 E = normalize(frEyeCam);
   vec3 R = reflect(-frLightCam,frNormalCam);

   float cosAlpha = clamp( dot( E,R ), 0.0,1.0 );
   float spec = pow(cosAlpha,4.0)*5.0;
   att += ((spec + clamp( dot(frNormalCam,frLightCam)*(1.0-ambient), 0.0,1.0 ))*lightAtt+ambient)*frLMat[i].w;
  }
 //}

//if(z>1.7) att = att-(z-1.7)*1.7;
//if(frPos.y>2.0) att = att-abs((frPos.y-2.0)*1.7);
FragColor.xyz = texture( myTextureSampler, oUV ).rgb * att;//*lightAtt;// frColor * att;
FragColor.w=texture(myTextureSampler,oUV).w;
vec3 gamma = vec3(1.0/0.85);
gamma = vec3(1.0/0.8);
FragColor.xyz = pow(FragColor.xyz,gamma)*(frBlackness+vec3(0.05))+vec3(0.06);

FragColor.a = frOpacity;
if (frBoolGUI==1) FragColor = texture(myTextureSampler,oUV);
}
```

(Please excuse the clumsy code, im only testing right now).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm a bit rusty when it comes to android shaders, but try setting float precision to "high"